# How does G*Power calculate sensitivity in z-test for two independent proportions

Tags: experiment-design, statistical-power, ab-test, cohens-d, gpower

I am trying to recreate sensitivity calculation in Python by applying the same methodology as used in G*Power

z-tests > Proportions: Difference Between Two Independent Proportions > Sensitivity: Compute the required effect size

[image]

But I am not able to find any information on the underlying formula used, even in the [official documentation](https://www.psychologie.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Fakultaeten/Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche_Fakultaet/Psychologie/AAP/gpower/GPowerManual.pdf). The only thing I've found in the software itself is that it uses "Cohen's h" for calculating the effect size.

Would appreciate any help regarding the calculations. I want to do these in Python but it doesn't looks like it has a library for that. Statsmodels are only able to perform power analysis with Cohen's d.

Comment: Strong hint: the effect sizes $h$ shown in your two screen shots are in the ratio $\sqrt{100/1000},$ the inverse square roots of the sample sizes.

Comment: @whuber sorry, I can't make anything of it. I'm not too strong on statistics unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Statsmodels does not have a dedicated function for this.

However, the z-test is based on generic normal test for the difference of the (transformed) means of two independent samples.

```
import statsmodels.stats.power as smp

smp.NormalIndPower().solve_power(effect_size=None, power=0.8, nobs1=1000, alpha=0.1, ratio=1, alternative='larger')
0.09495162823574568

smp.NormalIndPower().solve_power(effect_size=None, power=0.8, nobs1=100, alpha=0.1, ratio=1, alternative='larger')
0.30026052525013747
```

R package `pwr` has an equivalent function, e.g. for computing power
`p = pwr.2p.test(h=0.3, n=80, sig.level=0.05, alternative="greater")`

Aside: the initial statsmodels power computation were written as equivalents for R package `pwr` and G*Power.
see for example section "Tests for two Proportions (Normal Approximation)" in
https://jpktd.blogspot.com/2013/03/statistical-power-in-statsmodels.html
More recent additions to power and sample size functions in statsmodels were often based on the documentation of NCSS/PASS.

background:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_h

Also, there other methods for comparing two proportions that have better statistical properties, e.g. available as `method` argument in statsmodels.
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.test_proportions_2indep.html